# adding a button in django admin programmatically

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have a model called "Process" and I want to rename its button in the `admin_changelist` view. I want to limit the overwriting of templates where possible.

I created a custom form called `SingleForm` and a form called `MultipleForm` and I want a button that leads to each form.
So I tried the following:

Template first:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    <li>
        <a href="/admin/app/process/add_set/" class="addlink">
            Add multiple Processes
        </a>
    </li>
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

ModelAdmin:

```
class ProcessAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [path("add_set/", self.add_process_set),]
        return my_urls + urls

    def add_process_set(self, request):
        return MultipleForm
```

But I only end up with `Process with ID “add_set” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?`

Bonus question: How can I ONLY show the the button for `add_set` and omit the normal `add` button (I'd prefer without overwriting the template)?